# Call to undefined function oci_connect() even though oci8_12c is checked

Tags: php, oracle, apache, oracle12c

i am using wampserver and i'm trying to connect to oracle database through our network using :

```
$conn = oci_connect('rac1.localnetwork.com:1540/prod1.localnetwork.com', 'username', 'password') or die(could not connect:'.oci_error);
```

but what i get is an error message `Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()`

i have enabled oci8_12c in wampserver-php options but nothing.
i also don't know if i need to use oracle instant client so i didn't install it

Comment: The PHP Extension is only a conduit between PHP and Instant Client, so yes you do need to install it

Comment: how can i use it when im just a client and oracle is in another server?

Comment: Instant Client looks after the network comms

Comment: From [requirements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php): *requires Oracle 12c, 11g, 10g or 9iR2 client libraries* and *When PHP is on a different machine, use the free [Oracle Instant Client libraries](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html).*